# Android ImageButton Layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, imagebutton

Hi everyone I want to create an image button in android but the image that I want to import for that image button it doesn't fit the buttons layout. Anyone knows how could I make the image to fit the buttons width and height ? So basically the buttons width and height out scales my images width and scale.Many thanks in advance.!

My code: (from comment)

```
<ImageButton 
   android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
   android:src="@drawable/imagebtn2" 
   android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: Show your xml file with relevant code

Comment: you can use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: fitxy didn't work and my xml file is a relative layout and the image button code looks like this:

Comment: 'code'            <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/imagebtn2" 
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

Comment: test other `scaleType` and see what is the best for you

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a different `scaleType` on your `ImageButton`.

Refer to this for a list of possible `ScaleType`s: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

You can set the [`ScaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android%3ascaleType) in the xml like this:

```
<ImageButton
 ....
 android:scaleType="center"
 ....
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help but I am trying to change the scaleType but it doesn't change to any of the option that android gives me.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put image as button then you have to resize the size of the images which you are planning to put as buttons.

android supports different types of layouts such as hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi in which the resolutions of the screen changes accordingly.

[Here is link to resize the images [HERE](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5,100&name=ic_example)

after you save the images of different sizes it is supposed to put in respected drawable folders of respected project.